# Show more result from database with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm trying to create news block with AJAX in my template. so i wrote a simple code, in HTML Part:

```
<a href="javascript:ShowPost();">Show Posts</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

jQuery Part:

```
function ShowPost(){
  $.post(dir + 'engine/ajax/posts.php', {action:"showpost"},
    function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
});
};
```

PHP Part:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "showpost") {    
 $db->query( "SELECT title FROM post LIMIT 0,5 " );
  while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) {
   echo $row['title']."<br>";
  }    
}
```

Question is, how i can get more result after first click? for example, after **first** click on **Show Posts** link, i can show the 5 news from database. after **second** click on Show Posts link i need to show 6 to 10 news, in **third** click get result from 11 to 15 and continue ...

i hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your implementation you need to keep track how many items you have shown and pass the page number in. For example:

jQuery Part:

```
var pageNumber = 0; 
function ShowPost() {   
   pageNumber++;   
   $.post(dir+ 'engine/ajax/posts.php', {action:"showpost", pageNum: pageNumber},
      function(data) {
       $("#result").html(data); 
   }); 
};
```

Disclaimer: I m not a PHP developer so please treat teh code below as pseudo-code.

PHP Part:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "showpost") {    
var pageSize = 5;  
var pageNumber = $_POST['pageNumber'];    
var from = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;   
var to = pageNumber * pageSize;  
$db->query( "SELECT title FROM post LIMIT " + from + "," + pageSize);   
while ( $row = $db->get_row()) {    echo $row['title']."<br>";   }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the pagination limit in ur query

```
var offset = -5;
function ShowPost(){
offset = offset + 5;
  $.post(dir + 'engine/ajax/posts.php', {action:"showpost",offset:offset},
    function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
});
};

PHP part

if ($_POST['action'] == "showpost") {

$vOffset = $_POST['offset'];    
 $db->query( "SELECT title FROM post LIMIT $vOffset,5 " );
  while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) {
   echo $row['title']."<br>";
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a hidden field in html and update it's value after every success call and when next time you call for next record send that value in post.

```
<input type="hidden" name="limit" value="5">
<a href="javascript:ShowPost();">Show Posts</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```